# JavaScript prompt doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a simple math practice program in javascript. Different values are given in a prompt alert and the answer is compared with the user input. This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculations</title>

<script language = "javascript">

generate();

function generate() {
{   
var calc = Math.floor(math.random() * 3 + 1);


if (calc == 1){
    calcSort == "+"
}else if(calc == 2){
    calcSort == "*";
} else if (calc == 3){
    calcSort == "/";
}

var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

var answer;

if (calc == 1){
    answer = num1 + num2;
} else if (calc == 2){
    answer = num1 * num2;
} else if (calc == 3){
    answer = num1 / num2;
}

var userAnswer = prompt("What is " + num1 + calcSort + num2 + "?");

if (userAnswer == answer){
    alert("correct");
} else {
    alert("fail");
}


}

</script>

</head>
</html>
```

The prompt doesn't appear, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Comment on Alex W's answer moved here:</sup>

In addition to Alex W's answer, you're trying to assign `calcSort` using the equality operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`), and you are defining `calcSort` in global scope (bad). Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/695BK/1

Also, just for fun, I thought I would show you how you could easily clean up your code a bit to make it more maintainable. The multiple code blocks that compare `calc` to a number is, to me, a code smell. I tucked away all the logic for each `calc` result into a array of little helper objects. Then you can randomly pick an operation from the array. When you want to add another operation, you simply add an item to the `operations` array:

```
function generate() {

    var operations = [
        { symbol: '+', calc: function(a, b) { return a + b; }}, // 0
        { symbol: '*', calc: function(a, b) { return a * b; }}, // 1
        { symbol: '/', calc: function(a, b) { return a / b; }}  // 2
    ];

    var calc = Math.floor(Math.random() * operations.length + 1) - 1;
    var operation = operations[calc];

    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    var answer = operation.calc(num1, num2);

    var userAnswer = prompt("What is " + num1 + operation.symbol + num2 + "?");

    if (userAnswer == answer) {
        alert("correct");
    } else {
        alert("fail");
    }
}
```

Here's a working demo of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/695BK/3/

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra `{` at the beginning of the function declaration for `generate()`, also `math` is not defined because you need to use `Math` (case-sensitive) to use the utility functions.

Comment: Also, you're trying to assign `calcSort` using the equality operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`), and you are defining `calcSort` in global scope (bad). Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/695BK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- You have an extra `{` at the start of your function
- JS is case sensitive, so use `Math` not `math`
- You used `==` instead of `=` to try to assign values to `calcSort`

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfb97/

Note that you should declare all of your variables with `var` or they'll be global - currently you don't declare `calcSort`.

Note also that the first two problems above could be found if you check your browser's JS console for errors. The missing `{` would give an "Unexpected end of input" error, while the second would give "ReferenceError: math is not defined". (The `==` versus `=` thing is not actually a syntax error so it won't be reported in the console.)